# Removing special characters: Serverside Javascript + Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript

I'm currently learning Ampscript and SSJS for an email project. I'm trying to remove special characters to a specific object that is being called.
I've came across some things that I think that could help but isnt sure how to use them.

Creating a template for an exact target email. Thought I could use the string.replace as show below. What would be some other options if any?

```
string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
```

Current code section below : the @img automatically pull content with special characters that needs to be removed before being used in the email

```
If RowCount(@customTemplate) != 0 Then
    Set @costumTemplate = True
    Set @img = Lowercase(Replace(@first_artist, ' ','_'))
  ElseIf RowCount(@locationTemplate) != 0 Then
    Set @locationTemplate = True
    Set @img = Lowercase(Replace(@venue_name,' ','_'))
  EndIf
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is that expression working for you already? You're just asking if there's another way to implement the same thing?

Comment: It works however its not pulling  the objects with non special character names.

Comment: Not pulling them? Maybe it's more clear to our `marketing-cloud` experts, but I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of a string that's not getting handled properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise against using SSJS in your emails, especially since there is a native AMPScript function for doing the same thing.

Here are a few regex examples [from my blog](http://sprignaturemoves.com/regex-in-ampscript/):

```
%%[
var @s, @o, @p, @m

outputLine(concat("<h4>Strip leading zeroes from a string</h4>"))
set @s = "0000012345"
set @p = "^0*(\d+)$"
set @o = RegExMatch(@s, @p, 1)
outputLine(concat("input:  ",@s,"<br>"))
outputLine(concat('pattern: "',@p,'"<br>'))
outputLine(concat("output: ",@o,"<br>"))

outputLine(concat("<h4>Check for all digits, no match</h4>"))
set @s = "12345x"
set @p = "^\d*$"
set @o = RegExMatch(@s, @p , 0)
outputLine(concat("input: ",@s,"<br>"))
outputLine(concat('pattern: "',@p,'"<br>'))
outputLine(concat("output: ",@o,"<br>"))

outputLine(concat("<h4>Check for all digits, match</h4>"))
set @s = "12345"
set @p = "^\d*$"
set @o = RegExMatch(@s, @p , 0)
outputLine(concat("input: ",@s,"<br>"))
outputLine(concat('pattern: "',@p,'"<br>'))
outputLine(concat("output: ",@o,"<br>"))

outputLine(concat("<h4>Replace parenthetical text with space</h4>"))
set @s = "whee (whatever it is) whoop"
set @p = "\s\(.+\)\s"
set @m = RegExMatch(@s, @p, 0 , "IgnoreCase")
set @o = replace(@s,@m, " ")
outputLine(concat("input:  ",@s,"<br>"))
outputLine(concat('pattern: "',@p,'"<br>'))
outputLine(concat("match: ",@m,"<br>"))
outputLine(concat("replaced: ",@o,"<br>"))

]%%
```

**Reference:**

[RegExMatch() Function](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/regexmatch/)

Comment: Thanks! The original create used both ampscript * SSJS. Since I'm new with  ampscript I wasn't aware there was a way to remove special characters in ampscript.

Comment: after the its matched how could I remove it from the string before I use it

Comment: you just use the `replace()` function -- like in the last example

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I'm either doing it wrong or maybe its the fact I cant find a pattern to match Accent letters like a few of these: [link](http://bit.ly/1woX9jY )  Or maybe I'm explaining myself correctly. I'm trying to make sense of it at this point